# Load Java KeyStore for one alias?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, private-key

Does anyone know if it is possible to load a KeyStore so that it only prompts for the password for the given alias?

Example:

In my key store i have two private keys: Alice's Encryption Certificate and Bob's Encryption Certificate.

When i load my key store:

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
keyStore.load(null);
```

I am prompted for both Alice's and Bob's key store password. Once they are entered i can use `getKey("Alice's Encryption Certificate", null);` to retrieve Alice's private key. My keys are protected by Entrust's Security Provider, it is who prompts me for the passwords upon loading the key store. If i do not enter Bob's password and try to get his key it will return null, which is fine, but i would like to avoid the password prompt.

Is it possible to somehow specify that i only want Alice's key before loading the key store so i am never prompted for Bob's password?

Thanks.

Comment: hm, where are you asked about the passwords of both?

Comment: My keys are protected by Entrust's Security Provider, it prompts me for both passwords.

Comment: how? are you doing this with code (show the whole related code), or via keytool?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Bozho. The MSCAPI provider talks to ESP, I do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue and couldn't find a way to do it. Basically, you are asking if there is a way to load the keystore partially. It makes things more complicated that MSCAPI provider ignores any password you provide.

We get around the issue by storing only one key With MSCAPI keystore. It turns out this works better with the security model of Smartcard also.

Comment: Just silly, it should prompt for a password when you are trying to export a private key, not just load the store. Thanks ZZ, i will leave this question open for another day to see if anyone has an answer, if not i will accept yours.

Comment: We had the same problem though clearing the MY keystore was out of the question since other systems rely on static certificates installed in addition to the USB token.  We had to create a service that loads it and eliminate other keys.  Also, We found a way to hook on the USB events and be notified on the insertion and removal of a key, this allowed us to further the house cleaning and reduce somewhat the amount of pop-ups though we did not yet eliminate them completely.