# How to prevent popups when loading a keystore

Tags: java, windows, x509certificate, smartcard, cryptoapi

Hi as corollary to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959543/load-java-keystore-for-one-alias) question I wanted to ask if you know how to prevent the poping of dialogue either to ask for password or to ask to insert a certificate.

We are currently building a system where we have to use the windows keystore to get certificates that are stored on USB token containing both reader and certificate.  Unlike the original question we do not experience problems when loading the keystore but when we are accessing it.  If there is only a single certificate in the keystore no problem, we get the appropriate password popup at the appropriate time and that's it.  However if a second USB key gets inserted in the system and later removed the entry remains in the keystore and from then-on every time we try to access information in the keystore we get a popup to insert the key.  This occurs for every certificates in the store for which the key is not currently connected to the computer.

The system we are interfacing with that requires these certificates necessitates that we perform multiple cryptographic operations and to have these popups to come up every times is rather annoying to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug with your Windows CSP for the tokens. Once the certificates are added to the store, they need to be removed when the device is removed, either by the CSP or some additional "removal" utility.

You can check from certificate manager, what happens if you enter a single key and then remove it, do the certificates disappear from the "my certificates" list.

Comment: no they do not, I have to remove them manually if they are ever to dissapear

Comment: So you can a) file a bug against your hardware provider to fix their CSP b) use some additional software to trigger the removal event when the hardware is removed.

Comment: thanks for your help, sorry for the late reply.  I tried this and it did remove a certain amount of pop-ups though some remain.  Specifically if there are certificates in the store for which the USB key is not plugged in then I get a pop-up prompting insertion for each of them as I load the key store but before I can take any actions.  Filing a bug is currently impossible as the provider does not seem to allow it (recent merger I suppose) furthermore we are not in control of the drivers installed, a government agency is.  I will continue along this path to resolve the remaining problems.